# C++ Merge Overlapping Strings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let's say that I have string A: "info_mesh", and I want to add it string B: "mesh_foo".

However, I want string "info_mesh_foo", not string "info_meshmesh_foo".

I can't just say:

```
std::string A = "randomstuffoverlap", B = "overlapwithmorestuff"
std::string C = A + B;
```

Because I would end up with:

```
C = "randomstuffoverlapoverlapwithmorestuff",
```

when I want:

```
C = "randomstuffoverlapwithmorestuff"
```

without the "overlap" mentioned twice, as if the created string had a "mesh" of two strings.

However, I also would want this to work if:

```
std::string A = "juststuff", B = "unrelatedstuff", C;
//std::string C should be made equal to "juststuffunrelatedstuff".
```

(so there is No shared substring between them)

How would I go about doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you recognize the "shared" part?

Comment: *However, I also would want this to work if A is not even related to B, or if there is a longer shared substring between them.* -- You need to post more examples instead of describing other scenarios.

Comment: How would you do this if this was not C++, but pencil and paper?  That's the first step -- come up with a plan first before writing any code.

Comment: the shared part can by anything?

Comment: Yes - as long as they are the same substring.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
std::string A = "randomstuffoverlap", B = "overlapwithmorestuff", C;
size_t pos = A.find_last_of(B[0]);
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    std::string::difference_type d = A.size() - pos;
    if (A.substr(pos) == B.substr(0, d))
        C = A + B.substr(d);
    else
        C = A + B;
}
else
    C = A + B;
std::cout << C << std::endl;
```

Comment: Will fail if there are repetitions in the shared part. E.g.: `std::string A = "randomstuffoverlapo", B = "overlapowithmorestuff"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting with the maximum possible (full overlap), loop down until it fits, and then return the result from overlapping them:

```
std::string overlap(std::string_view a, std::string_view b) {
    for (auto n = std::min(a.size(), b.size());; --n) {
        if (b.endswith(a.substr(0, n))) // b.substr(b.size() - n) == a.substr(0, n)
            return std::string(b) + a.substr(n);
        else if (a.endswith(b.substr(0, n))) // a.substr(a.size() - n) == b.substr(0, n)
            return std::string(a) + b.substr(n);
}
```

If you cannot use [C++20 `std::string_view::endswith()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/ends_with), use the alternative in the comment.

Comment: That's kind of ineffective - need to execute substr on each iteration

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername `.substr()` on a `std::string_view` is trivial, so not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has taken me a while, but I have this function:

```
string overlapjoin(string a, string b) {
    for (long long x = (b.length()<= a.length())? b.length(): a.length(); x > 0; --x)
        if (a.substr(a.length() - x, a.length() - 1) == b.substr(0, x))
            return(a.substr(0, a.length() - x) + b);
    return(a + b);
}
```

Which can also be expressed as, if you want a limit to shared characters:

```
string overlapjoin(string a, string b, int maxlength) {
    for (long long x = maxlength; x > 0; --x)
        if (a.substr(a.length() - x, a.length() - 1) == b.substr(0, x))
            return(a.substr(0, a.length() - x) + b);
    return(a + b);
}
```